# What does the 'a' attribute in lsattr mean?

Tags: linux, bash, command-history, xattr

I was trying to remove some old history from my `.bash_history` file, but I was receiving this message:

```
[john ~] /home/john $ mv .bash_history .bas
mv: impossible to move `.bash_history' to `.bas': Operation not permited
```

I suspected the file/directory permission:

```
[john ~] /home/john $ ls -ld .bash_history .
drwxrwx--T+ 5 root       john 4096 Out 11 19:45 .
-rw-r--r--  1 john john 2977 Out 10 14:36 .bash_history
[john ~] /home/john $
```

Then I tried:

```
[john ~] /home/john $ lsattr .bash*
-----a------- .bash_history
------------- .bash_logout
------------- .bash_profile
------------- .bashrc
[john ~] /home/john $
```

Probably it is this `a` attribute; what does it mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `a` attribute means that the file is append-only: you can't overwrite it or delete it, only append data to it. This is explained in the [`chattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) man page. Only root can remove the attribute.

The practical consequence is that you can't erase your old history lines. This is presumably intended as a security measure by your system administrator. I'm not completely convinced it's secure, but off the top of my head I can't think of a way to remove some of the file's contents. (It is however easy to bypass the file and run commands without their showing in the history, which is why it's not a particularly useful security measure against competent users — an obvious way being to run the commands from something other than bash.).

Comment: Also, going through the history command and using the -d option may allow line deletion even with this setting in place